# infopath developed forms can not be published to sharepoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I've recentle installed sharepoint 2019 and I'm very new to this field. I used Infopath to customize a "new Item" page, then published it successfully. but when I click on "new item" in sharepoint list, I get the following error:

> The form cannot be rendered. This may be due to a misconfiguration of the Microsoft SharePoint Server State Service. For more information, contact your server administrator.

I made some search, found out that I have to configure State Service Application on the server using command like this:

```
New-SPStateServiceDatabase –Name "State Service Database" | New-SPStateServiceApplication –Name "State ServiceApplication" | New-SPStateServiceApplicationProxy -DefaultProxyGroup
```

But there was no such command (or "`Get-SPStateServiceApplication`") available in powershell. There was another way for enabling a service in central administration, but again there was no such a service there.

I've no idea how to solve this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself! using what is described in this Page:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33962.sharepoint-2016-state-service-application-step-by-step.aspx